# How to copy from tmux with the mouse, to the OSX clipboard

Tags: macos, mouse, clipboard, remote-server, tmux

I connect to a remote server with VS Code through ssh, using https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh. I open a Terminal window in VS code. Using the mouse to copy text to the OSX clipboard works nicely here: I can select text with the mouse in this terminal window, copy it with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste it in any other OSX application with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. However, I need to run tmux on the remote server. Once I start tmux, I can select text with the mouse (it briefly flashes yellow) but I cannot paste it anywhere else. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select text with the mouse while you keep the Option key pressed.

You may want to enable mouse support in your tmux config for some additional integrations:

```
set -g mouse on
```

These are covered in [tmux's manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html)

Comment: 1) Option key doesn't work if I have `set -g mouse on` in my config 2) neither solution allows me to paste the selected code in other windows.

Comment: Can you paste your tmux in the original question? The option key allows to select text with the mouse even if you have an empty `.tmux.conf`, both in iTerm and the default Terminal application.